# Laravel Backpack Admin Login 419 Page Expired

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I created a new Laravel project for both APIs and Admin. I first installed Sanctum for the API authentication and then I installed Backpack. After the Backpack installation, I hit the admin URL and attempted to log in but I got the 419 page expired error. It was the same for registration. This is not the first time this is happening. What could be wrong? I am using Laravel 8 and Backpack 4.0.x

Comment: You should include some example code with your question

Comment: i have not written any code. i just followed the installation guides for Laravel, Sanctum and Backpack. From the video tutorial for Backpack, I am not supposed to write any code, the login should just work

Comment: Do you make a post request? I have seen this error '419 page expired' before when the csrf is missing.

Comment: Make sure to put your domain as the `SESSION_DOMAIN` value in your `.env` file.

Comment: Please use proper APP_URL. if you are using php artisan serve, this will open the app on port 8000 (if the port is free). please mention the same in the APP_URL too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Backpack Admin. I face the same problem.
Try the  command

```
php artisan key:generate
```